# Zendesk OAuth2.0 implementation in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, jwt, zendesk

Currently, we are using `Zendesk Android SDK v1.6.1.1` and we do user authentication with help of JWT token. As there are some limitations when you authenticated by JWT token, we are looking for OAuth2.0 base authentication.

Is there any provision to do OAuth2.0 authentication through Android SDK? Or is there any other way to do? Thanks!